# Use D3D9 Fonts by linking to Windows 10 SDK

Tags: directx, direct3d

Is it possible to use D3D9 fonts by linking to DirextX version in Windows 10 SDK ?

Below is the type of code I would like to run. But I can't find fonts supported in Windows 10 SDK

```
    D3DXFONT_DESC fontDesc;
    fontDesc.Height          = 80;
    fontDesc.Width           = 40;
    fontDesc.Weight          = FW_BOLD;
    fontDesc.MipLevels       = 0;
    fontDesc.Italic          = true;
    fontDesc.CharSet         = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
    fontDesc.OutputPrecision = OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS;
    fontDesc.Quality         = DEFAULT_QUALITY;
    fontDesc.PitchAndFamily  = DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE;
    _tcscpy(fontDesc.FaceName, _T("Ariel"));

    D3DXCreateFontIndirect(gd3dDevice, &fontDesc, &mFont);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows 10 SDK includes the 'core headers' for Direct3D 9 API, but does *not* contain the D3DX utility library. **D3DX9, D3DX10, and D3DX11 are deprecated, and none of them are provided in the Windows 8.x SDK or Windows 10 SDK.**

You can still use the [legacy, end-of-life DirectX SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directx-sdk--august-2009-) to get D3DX9. You can mix the legacy DirectX SDK with the Windows 10 SDK, but you need to use the *reverse* order for the include/lib paths. These details are on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directx-sdk--august-2009-).

> Keep in mind that using D3DX also means your application continues to rely on the legacy DirectSetup which in many cases it could otherwise avoid using. See [Not So Direct Setup](https://aka.ms/dxsetup).

See [Where is the DirectX SDK (2015 Edition)?](https://aka.ms/dxsdk)

> Of course, Direct3D 9 itself is 'legacy'. There are replacements for all the D3DX functionality available if using Direct3D 11 or later. See [Living without D3DX](https://aka.ms/Kfsdiu)